# ¿Cómo obtengo la fecha y la mando a PHP correctamente?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Quiero enviar una fecha a mi archivo *PHP* (**display.php**) para mostrar los datos de mi base de datos.

¿Qué puedo hacer diferente para lograr esto?

Para crear mi calendario, uso el siguiente código:

```js
$(function() {
  var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var d = new Date();
  var day = d.getDate();
  var month = d.getMonth();
  var year = d.getFullYear();

  function days(month, year) {
    //last day of month
    var lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();

    //first day of month
    var a = new Date("1 ," + months[month] + "," + year + "");

    //month string
    $("#date").html(months[month] + " " + year);

    var counter = 0;
    $("#days").html("<tr>");
    for (var i = 1; i < lastDay + 1; i++, counter++) {

      //blank space
      if (i == 1) {
        for (var j = 0; j < a.getDay(); j++, counter++) {
          $("#days").append("<td></td>");
        }
      }

      //new week
      if (counter % 7 == 0) {
        $("#days").append("</tr><tr>");
      }

      //display days
      $("#days").append("<td class='day_active'><a onclick='dayClicked(" + i + "," + month + "," + year + ")'>" + i + "</a></td>");

    }
  };

  //day click
  window.dayClicked = function(day, month, year) {
    days(month, year);
    //ajax post
    month = month + 1;
    var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "display.php",
      dataType: "text",
      data: {
        today: today
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert("date: " + data);
      }

    });


  };


  //left click
  $("#prev").on("click", function() {
    if (month == 0) {
      year--;
      month = 12;
    }
    month--;
    days(month, year);
  });

  //right click
  $("#next").on("click", function() {
    if (month == 11) {
      year++;
      month = -1;
    }
    month++;
    days(month, year);
  });

  days(month, year);

});
```

```css
.btn,
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn" id="prev">&lang;</span>
<span id="date"></span>
<span class="btn" id="next">&rang;</span>
<table>
  <tr id="weekdays">
    <td>Su</td>
    <td>Mo</td>
    <td>Tu</td>
    <td>We</td>
    <td>Th</td>
    <td>Fr</td>
    <td>Sa</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="days"></tbody>
</table>
```

Lo que tengo en **display.php** es lo siguiente:

```php
 if(isset($_POST['today'])){
    $date = $_POST['today'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE eventDate='$date' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
      while($row = json_encode(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))){
        echo "<div class='wrap'>";
        echo "<h2>".$row['title']."</h2>";
        echo "<p>".$row['detail']."</p>";
        echo "</div>";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: pudes hacer una llamada AJAX

Comment: Por lo que he probado el codigo funciona bien, cual es el problema?